# Complexity of converting a propositional formula to disjunctive normal form

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, computational-complexity

If $\varphi$ is a propositional formula, what is the complexity of the problem of converting $\varphi$ into an equivalent disjunctive normal form? What about an equisatisfiable disjunctive normal form? I see a variety of information online but none states the complexity class explicitely.

Comment: The satisfiability problem for disjunctive normal forms (DNF) is trivial, but for general forms is NP-hard, so converting $\varphi$ to an equivalent DNF is also NP-hard.

Comment: What about NP-completeness @Sam?

Comment: Ahh.. That seems to be a deep question, at first I thought it would be equally simple but now I don't see an easy way to prove it. Could it be that it's not even in NP?